# Typescript variable generics

Tags: typescript

I know this is possibly doesn't exist, but can Typescript have a variable number of generics, each of their own type?

For example, instead of having something like `function name(...args: any[])`, I'd like to have a way that you could so something like

```
function name<T1, T2, T3...>(arg1: T1, arg2: T2, ...)
```

So if I were to do

```
name('string', 123, true)
```

I can then have the types of `string`, `number`, `boolean` as my generic types in the method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Full-blown [variadic kinds](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5453) are not implemented in TypeScript, but luckily for your particular use case you can use [tuple types in rest/spread expressions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions) introduced in TS3.0:

```
function nameFunc<T extends any[]>(...args: T) {};

nameFunc('string', 123, true); // T inferred as *tuple* [string, number, boolean]
```

And you can access the individual member types via numeric [lookup](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#keyof-and-lookup-types) types:

```
// notice that the return type is T[1]
function secondItem<T extends any[]>(...args: T): T[1] {
  return args[1];
}
const num = secondItem("string", 123, true); // number
```

Hope that helps; good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It definitely is possible I guess. In below example, we should have type inference at every step while invoking the function getProperty.

```
function getProperty<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K) {
    return obj[key];
}

export interface User {
    name: string;
}

type k = keyof User;

const user = { name: 'Krantisinh' };

getProperty<User, k>(user, 'name');
```